# Cannot compile TpLink Archer T9UH adapter drivers on Kali Linux VM

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, make

I downloaded the drivers for linux from Tp Link website but when I try to run 'make' command to compile them I get the following error:

```
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-kali1-amd64/build M=/root/Documents/rtl8814AU_linux_v4.3.17_13720.20150622_beta_led  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.13.0-kali1-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1635: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I will be grateful if somebody helps.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`/lib/modules/4.13.0-kali1-amd64/build` should be a symbolic link, pointing to the kernel source code from which `4.13.0-kali1-amd64` was compiled.

Typically, most distributions have a "kernel-source" or similar package which contains this source. Install it.

My opinion is that kernel compilation should be better if it is done from your distribution independently.